# ServiceStack Ormlite class with temporary field

Tags: c#, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

Is it possible to define temporary fields to hold data (that are not in the table schema) in a ServiceStack OrmLite POCO class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely. You can simply add an `[Ignore]` attribute on the properties that are not part of your schema.

[From the documentation:](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#ignoring-dto-properties)

> Ignoring DTO Properties
>
> You may use the [Ignore] attribute to denote DTO properties that are not fields in the table. This will force the SQL generation to ignore that property.

Example:

```cs
public class MyTable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Ignore]
    public string ExtraData { get; set; } // This field will not be included in SQL
}
```